# Terminology for smoothing methods: kernel density estimation, kernel smoothing, etc

Tags: terminology, spatial, kernel-smoothing, smoothing, weighted-mean

I'm using what I have been referring to as 'kernel density estimation' to estimate the rates of a series of variables `a, b, c` from noisy observations distributed in 1-, 2- and 3-dimensional space. The variables being estimated are relative proportions - `a+b+c=1` at every point. The approach boils down to taking a weighted average of all the values where the weights are a function of distance from the point of interest to each observation. That function is usually a static Gaussian function, but I've also used a square kernel (all points within distance `k` are weighted 1, all others are weighted 0), k-nearest neighbours (the nearest `k` points are weighted 1, all other points are weighted 0), or a dynamic Gaussian kernel (weights are determined with a Gaussian function but `σ` is set for each estimate such that the sum of weights is always `k`).

My question is about terminology -

- Can I reasonably refer to all of these as kernel density estimation, regardless of the kernel function?
- Is it okay to refer to these as kde when I'm working with relative proportions?
- I see a range of other terms around - kernel smoother, kernel smoothing, kernel density smoothing, weighted moving averages, nearest neighbour smoothing, etc. - are there really differences here, or are some of these different names for the same methods?

Comment: Kernel smoothing implies use of a kernel, a set of weights. It's density smoothing if and only if the result is an estimate of probability density. Moving averages such as Hanning (weights 1:2:1 / 4 for previous : present : next) are kernel smoothers, but need not be described as such. Depending where you come from, smoothing may also be regarded as part of filtering. Some people talk about median filters, so the term has grown beyond convolution of a series and a set of weights.

Comment: Thank you, I think that makes sense. So in my case, my variables are probabilities - the reason a+b+c=1 is that this is estimating the probability of mutually exclusive events one of which must happen. So am I right in understanding that would make it appropriate to use the term kde, but that 'kernel smoothing' is more general and so would apply either way?

Comment: Kernel smoothing is certainly more general than kernel density estimation. As it happens, I was playing a few days with smoothing three proportions, and wasn't surprised to find that a naive method based on smoothing each separately won't automatically respect the constraint that the total is 1.

Comment: oh, interesting! I haven't had this problem, but I think the way I've implemented this makes that inevitable - for each estimate, I'm dividing the sum of the kernel weighted values for the current variable at every point by the sum of all kernel weighted values at every point. as long as the raw values added up to one at each point, the estimates will do too.